# Variation of permutation of an array containing Integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, permutation

Given an array of intergers, write a program to print all the permutations of the numbers in the array. The output should be sorted in a non-increasing order.

For example for the array `{12, 4, 66, 8, 9}`, the output should be:

```
9866412
9866124
9846612
....
....
1246689
```

I thought of generating all permutations at the same time inserting them in a `BST`, then performing reverse inorder on `BST`.
This seems highly inefficient, as I'm storing the permutations, can we do better ?

Comment: We can do better. We can do a websearch for the problem, for example. Or we can ask a bunch of people to do the work for us.

Comment: @doomster people post here after doing a lot of research on the problem and putting a lot of effort by themselves. What do you think stackoverflow if for ? i feel for me it is to discuss problems i feel difficult to solve or when i feel a more optimized version might exist . sometimes when i am stuck in some problem related to office work  , i even post that problem to so that i can discuss with people here. If you call that " bunch of people to do the work for you".. let it be for you , for me its discussion

Answer (score 0):

c++ STL:

vector arr = ..
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end())
    do
    {
       // process your data here
    }while(next_permutation(arr.begin(),arr.end());

This do what you want for you in O(2^n). internally its implemented by swapping in efficient way. let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 0):

First sort the numbers using their digits (maybe converting them into strings). For instnace, 9 is greater than 11. You can implement a simple insertion sort for this.

So now you have a list of number sorted this way (let's say n1, n2, n3, n4).

Using this list you can easily get all the permutations already sorted, merging elements in the list and swapping the last one as the generation proceeds.

That is: n1n2n3n4, n1n2n4n3, n1n3n2n4... and so on.

Example: 

4, 11, 76, 100

100, 11, 4, 76

10011476, 10011764, 10041176...


About the complexity: sorting takes `k*n^2` (with the insertion sort, and you can save memory since it is in place), with `k` the longest size of a number (3 in the example, given by number 100), since if there are similar numbers you need to compare all their digit (like 10000 and 100001). Then you only need to generate all permutations and this takes `n!`. Final time complexity is `O(n!)` and no extra space is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python, module itertools has a solution, see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

If you have access to Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming* volume 4, fascicule 2, it has many solutions, recursive as well as iterative.

Also, RosettaCode has solutions in many languages, see [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations). The Fortran 77 solution is iterative, you may adapt it to fill your needs, or translate it in any language. It gives solutions in ascending lexicographic order.

Now, if I undestand what your are asking, you need solutions in decreasing order, considering ordering of strings of digits concatenated. It may be difficult to implement directly, since, for example (100,99,999) who be "less" than (99,100,999), which would be less than (999,99,100): "10099999" < "99100999" < "99999100". You can't simply use lexicographic order of lists of numbers. However, it's very easy to generate permutation in lexicographic order.

Answer (score 0):

For reasoning, I'd do it recursively:

- If the array has length 1, then output one single permutation (array itself)
- If there are two or more elements, pick one element at a time (greatest element first, going on to smaller ones until you reach the smallest). For each element `a` picked, you do the following:

  - Remove `a` from the array, and obtain an array containing one element less than the original array. Generate *recursively* all permutations of this newly obtained array, and prepend `a` in front of *each* recursively generated permutation.

This approach basically corresponds to your idea of storing permutations in a search tree (however, not a binary one), and enumerate them. Still, it uses the recursion stack to do so, and does not store the whole tree.

Another approach might use the [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system). This can be used to properly enumerate permutations. So you can "just count backwards and reconstruct the corresxponding permutations".